# How do I submit an form using PHP when the form destination is obscured?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, http

I am trying to submit a form on a website and the way the form is submitted seems to be replaced with some javascript. Trying to find where the http request is actually sent to has been a real pain. I'm having a hard time getting the actual url required. Normally I would just use cURL to create a post request. Is there any way to simulate button presses or run javascript on a website using PHP? Or is there any tools I can use to somehow snoop the actual url that the form gets submitted to?

**Edit**
I don't have any code to post because I don't know where to start with this problem. As I do not have the url to make the post request, it is pointless me doing this:

```
$url = 'https://id.oculus.com/US/en-US/login/';
$data = array('email' => 'bla', 'password' => 'things');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
$options = array(
        'http' => array(
                'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'method'  => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: I don't really have any code because I don't know where to start. As I said I don't have the url so doing a post request in PHP makes no sense. I'm trying to post the login details to this website https://id.oculus.com/US/en-US/login/ if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Javascript can simulate button presses, and PHP can echo Javascript.

Just use something like:

"echo 'document.getElementById("id_of_button").click();';"

That will simulate a button press on a button with the ID "id_of_button"

If that is not what you need, then if you haven't already, try [deobfuscating](http://jsbeautifier.org/) the Javascript, and THEN try analyzing it to try to find out what's going on.

---

Hopefully that helped!

This is my second answer!

Best Regards, -Gauched